# Windows 8 Monitor System going nuts

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have a MicroDP port on my laptop and I use a MicroDP to DVI computer to use my monitor. Up to today, it worked just fine. However, it refuses to work anymore.

The pictures attached are from BEFORE I plugged in my monitor. There is no change after I plug it in.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Note in the second picture, the project to a *connected* screen window is open. There's no connected screen.

Upon enabling the "Extend" mode in the second screen, this is the result:
[image]

Note that there is NO ACTUAL monitor plugged in.

TL;DR: PC isn't detecting monitor, instead it thinks a "ghost" monitor exists.

I dual-booted into Ubuntu for testing and it didn't even detect a second monitor, whether it was plugged in or not.

***Edit:*** Upon testing with a monitor at work with miniDP, it works. So, my adapter is broken. However, the ghost monitor still exists, even after reinstalling drivers.

Comment: If you have a ghost monitor you can just delete the display.

Comment: What display? Nothing in the device manager.

Comment: You don't delete a display through device manager.  You delete a display through `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution`

Comment: No display there either. It only shows in "extend" mode. When I delete that, it is still there.